# how to pull matching dates on db2?

Tags: sql, date, db2

I am attempting to create a query that will present when a driver purchased gas and what his odometer was on the date he purchased it.
Currently I am using two tables `ODOHIS` AND `FS_POS`
within the table `FS_POS` I will be using the columns `POS_DATE` AND `VOL_PFUEL` and within `ODOHIST` I will be using `READINGDATE` and `ODOMETER`

SO then my question is how can I pull the odometer readings only on the dates driver pumped gas?

I tried doing

```
WHERE POS_DATE = READINGDATE
```

but quickly realized that the chances that an odometer reading matched the same time as the fuel purchase was near impossible!

Please advise and thanks in advance!

Comment: What data types are POS_DATE and READINGDATE? You might want to give `select * from odohis inner join fs_pos on date(pos_date) = date(readingdate)` a try.

Comment: both are timestamps ! ill give that a go and ill let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method of getting the most recent odometer reading on or before each fill-up:

```
select fs.*,
       (select max(o.odometer)
        from odohis o
        where o.vehicleId = fs.vehicleId and o.reading_date <= fs.pos_date
       ) odometer,
       (select max(o.reading_date)
        from odohis o
        where o.vehicleId = fs.vehicleId and o.reading_date <= fs.pos_date
       ) reading_date
from fs_pos fs;
```